# Conditional Infile statement

Tags: sas

Is it possible using an infile statement to conditionally assign a read in value to one or another column in the dataset to be created, depending on what the value is?

```
data test;
infile '&filename' delimiter = ',' missover dsd lrecl 32767 firstobs = 2;
informat var_one 2.;
informat var_two $4.;
format var_one 2.;
format var_two $4.;
input
if length(item in question) = 2 then
var_one
else 
var_two $;
run;
```

In the code above 'item in question' is me filling in my knowledge gap and basically means assign the value being read in to one or the other column depending on it's length.

Obviously you can see I dont have the full correct syntax here, but could someone suggest to me what I would need to change and if this is even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please post test data... maybe rig an example up using DATALINES instead of INFILE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to input it into a temporary variable and then choose based on that.

```
data test;
infile '&filename' delimiter = ',' missover dsd lrecl 32767 firstobs = 2;
informat var_one 2.;
informat var_two $4.;
format var_one 2.;
format var_two $4.;
input temp $;
if length(temp) = 2 then var_one=input(temp,2.);
else var_two = temp;
run;
```

You could certainly do this on input though as well.

```
data test;
infile '&filename' delimiter = ',' missover dsd lrecl 32767 firstobs = 2;
informat var_one 2.;
informat var_two $4.;
format var_one 2.;
format var_two $4.;
input @; *start inputtingl
if length(scan(_infile_,1,',')) = 2 then 
  input var_one;
else 
  input var_two $;
run;
```

But I find the first method a bit simpler as you don't have to scan it.

Comment: Here's some discussion on the @ symbol re:conditional input. http://support.sas.com/kb/45/289.html

Answer (score 1):

Your problem really doesn't look like something that needs to conditionally run an `INFILE` statement. That would normally involve changing which file to read or perhaps changing which delimiter to use.

You can certainly conditionally run an `INPUT` statement. This is normally done when the input stream has many different record types. You read enough of the record to determine the type while holding the line with a trailing `@`.  Then based on the record type you read different variables form the line.

```
input rectype $ @ ;
if rectype='1' then input @1 rectype name age gender;
else input @1 rectype company_name job_title ;
```

But your problem looks more like something that you would just handle with conditionally executing assignment statements. First read it into a character string and test its length. Based on that you can decide which variable to store it into.

```
length temp $10 var_one 8 var_two $4 ;
input temp ;
if length(temp)<=2 then var_one = input(temp,2.);
else if length(temp) < 4 then var_two=temp;
else put 'WARING: Length too long.' temp= $quote. ;
```

Or just read it into the character string variable and convert it to the number.  You can suppress conversion errors by using `?` or `??` modifiers so that SAS will silently set the numeric variable to missing when the string does not look like a number.

```
length var_one 8 var_two $4 ;
input var_two ;
var_one = input(var_two, ??2.);
```

You could even blank out the character string if the value did look like a number.

```
if not missing(var_one) then call missing(var_two);
```